# How emission works

Tags: light

I want to know how an emission light works. I have a small room, A window and a sphere as light. I want the light from inside to pass through the transparent glass window and the light from the outside to also pass through the same window. I have set the strength to 100 yet the light is not passing out of the room.

If I were to make another object other than a glass window (Like a wall lantern for example), are the settings for the material the same or do I have to change them? If they are different how do I set the settings for both?

blender file [image]

getting error[image]

Comment: Umm maybe i missed something but from what i see your wall behind the window doesn't have a hole - so sure there can pass no light through it. If you cut a hole in the walls with a boolean modifier, it works fine.
Edit:I think you used archimesh and thats why the .blend does not work right for me. but still- when i cut a hole in the wall it works fine.

Comment: but the window having the glass material so light can pass from it why it need a hole.

Comment: Please watch: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Heg89K3ZMDo

Answer (score 1):

So the simple solution i case your .blend works the same as mine: add an solidify modifier and an boolean modifier (set to difference) that uses the object CTRL_Hole to both walls that are in the scene ("Room" and "Wall_cover"). Then it works fine.
[image]

edit- Answer to your previous question under my comment: The window doesn't need a hole it's the walls behind it (diffuse material) that need it for the light to pass through.

Comment: Thanks for that answer if i have a paper lantern will that works as i want that paper lantern light to be pass from the paper there is no hole to the lantern how it will work then.

Comment: use a translucent shader for the paper. It makes the light pass from one side to the other side of an object (like paper).

Comment: as soon as i click on apply its give an error an image add above.

Comment: Sorry i don't get what you mean maybe you should watch some tutorials about cycles in general - Andrew Price and CynicatPro on YouTube for example do nice tutorials.

Comment: I have applied the boolean tool as u said but its not working its giving error i have attach .gif file with whats error im getting

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple, a diffuse material that you have for the wall doesn't actually allow light to pass through it. You need to make it transparent a simple transparent or glass shader doesn't work. Make a material like this 
[image: here is the glassy material]

Comment: thanks for ur reply. sorry im weak in nodes as said above. If i want to add the paper or plastic other than glass can i remove only the glass shader. will transparent will be same